# How to add same column multiple times in mvcgrid in mvc3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Below is my code for `mvcgrid`. My model contains properties `Name`, `ProductCode`, `AvgWaight`.
I want to add Column for `ProductCode` 2 times. But at runtime argument exception is thrown as `"Column 'ProductCode ' already exist in the grid"`

```
 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Product Name ").SetWidth(200).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.ProductCode).Titled("Product Code").SetWidth(200).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.AvgWeight).Titled(" Avg. Weight").SetWidth(300).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
}).WithPaging(5)
```

How to add same column multiple times, with different titles.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Do it this way, it worked for me.

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Product Name").SetWidth(200).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);

    columns.Add(c => c.ProductCode).Titled("Product Code").SetWidth(200).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);

    columns.Add(c => c.ProductCode, "Duplicate Column").Titled("Product Code").SetWidth(200).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);

}
```